# Wordpress. Обернуть все посты после 3-го в контейнер, не нарушая пагинацию

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Требуется помощь в том, чтобы обернуть все последующе посты после 3-го в контейнер "X".

Сейчас код имеет следующий вид:

```
<?php 
$sn_args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'paged'  => $paged,
'cat' => '27,31,20',
'posts_per_page' => '11',
); ?>

$querysn = new WP_Query( $sn_args );

if ( $querysn->have_posts() ){?>

<?php 

while ( $querysn->have_posts() ) : $querysn->the_post() ; ?>
<?php $c++; if( !$paged && $c == 1) :?>
<?php include 'template-parts/content-news-first-fullheight.php'; ?>
<?php elseif( !$paged && $c > 1 && $c <= 3) :?>
<?php include 'template-parts/content-news-small-fullheight.php'; ?>

<?php else:?> 
<?php include 'template-parts/content-small.php'; ?>
<?php endif;?>  

<?php endwhile; }?>

<?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $querysn ) );?>
```

То есть, 1й пост имеет темплейт А, 2-й и 3-й посты имеют темплейт Б, а все остальные, что идут дальше, теймплейт В. 
Как выглядит сейчас:

```
post-1
post-2
post-3
post-4
...
post-last
```

Все посты, начиная с 4-го я и пытаюсь обернуть в отдельный контейнер, чтобы получилось следующее:

```
post-1
post-2
post-3
<div class="x">
  post-4...post-last
</div>
```

Не понимаю, как это сделать. Прошу помочь.
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Дейлайте через switch,  j,оберните в функцию и вызывайте.

```
switch ($c) {
case 1:
    include 'template-parts/content-news-first-fullheight.php'; 
    break;
case 2:
    include 'template-parts/content-news-small-fullheight.php';
    break;
case "3":
    include 'template-parts/content-news-small-fullheight.php';
    break;
case default:
    echo "Other situation";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, что ваш код меняет вид условий. Но, к сожалению, я всё равно не могу добиться, чтобы контейнер оборачивал нужные мне посты в виде:

    post-1
    post-2
    post-3
    <div class="x">
     post-4...post-last
    </div>

(в комментарии не вставить код, отредактировал сам вопрос для наглядности)